# How to get the blogs owned by a user?

Tags: multisite, users

I have setup WP MU and I would like to get a list of blogs a user owns. Is there a method that gets this info?

**More info:**
I only have one page for the user to login. I need to get the blogs they own to redirect to their own blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a method called

```
get_blogs_of_user($user_id);
```

Supply the user id and echo it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blogs_of_user

Comment: "+1" and "thanks". Added URL of documentation.